# Can I do a INSERT using select from another DB with the same table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, vbscript

I have a `person` table (sqlServer 2008r2) and are using .vbs and .bat files to sync some data from a table called `person` in `database A` to `database B`.

**Note** - The DB names are different but the table names are the same.  Because the `peson` table has 137 fields I am looking for a way to write both an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` statement.  How can I do thsi without listing 137 fields?

1. At the moment I connect to `database A` and populate a recordSet called RS with the `people` table records.
2. Then I loop through RS and query the `people` table in `database B`
3. If found I update people table in `database B` with the `people` table record from `database A`
4. If not found I insert the people record from `database A` into the `people` table on `database B`

Now this is nice and easy but since it has 137 fields I do not want to write a MASSIVE update and insert statements.  DO I have another option such as:

The table structures are identical between `people` on `database A` and `people` on `database B` but the recordset obtained in **step 1** above is using one one DB connection and the query in **step 2** is using a separate DB connection to a different DB instance on a different server.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a fully qualified name.

```
insert into DATABASE1.dbo.Person (columns)
select (columns) from DATABASE2.dbo.Person
```

Also there are others way to pump data from a database for another
You can take a look on your MSSMS it got a tool for that kind of thing.
Select one database and right button mouse to open the import/export wizard.
You can also take a look on replication, bulk copy, service broker, etc...

Comment: Thing is they are differenr DB connections.  How can you refer to two seperate DB connections on one query EG: strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE person_id < 1000000 ORDER BY person_id" then fire this by using the 'conn' connection like so set intRS = conn.execute(strSql).  My second query is strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people...." which gets fired using 'seconddaryConnection' like so set extRS = secondaryconn.execute(strSql).  Based on this how can I possibly write such a query

Comment: Additionaly both of the databases and tables are named the same...I just can see how this is possible.  Does anyone have an other ideas??  DO I really have to write an INSERT and an UPDATE statement containing 137 fields

Comment: Lastley you have used '(columns)' in your query.  The whole idea of my post was to ask if this could be done without listing 137 fields.  of course this would be easy to go from tables within the same DB.  My issue is the table names are identical, the database names are identical the two SQL2008R2 instances are on seperate servers

Comment: If both DBs are at the same server and you can access both with the same user you can access both tables using fully qualified names. If they are different server you can link one server to another and ad the servers names to the fully qualified name. If you can edit the query you can do it

Comment: You know you can "drag" your columns list from the MSSMS and drop it at a text, helps a lot. And you may want to list your columns if you want to by pass a identity column (if you got one)

Comment: Hi Jean.  Yes using MS to produce column names and listing them out is what I will do.  There is no shortcut here.....thanking you